# ASP.NET Identity Token Authentication Sign In method

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, single-page-application, access-token

In the ASP.NET Identity token authentication, I provide username and password to the /token api to get the token and put on the header of each request.

I have a registration wizard in my application, in one of the steps I register user information and create user account. The problem is I don't want to redirect the users to login page, so they can enter their username and password to call the /token api.

What I want to do is to sign the user in automatically after he/she finish the registration wizard without calling /token api. Because at the end of registration I don't have password and don't want to keep the password in client side.

Is there any way to sign the user in. Or any better solution.

Thanks,

Comment: IMO you better separate registration and sign-in. Users can understand the difference.you can always prompt the user to sign-in with their registered details at the end of the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good blog post by nakov.
He explains quite detail about what you want to achieve.
http://www.nakov.com/blog/2014/12/22/webapi-owin-identity-custom-login-service/

This is the GitHub link about the way he done.
[Git hub link](https://github.com/SoftUni/SPA-with-AngularJS/tree/master/Ads-REST-Services)

Comment: The problem with this approach is I don't have password. Consider this scenario. I am logged in as admin and I see the list of users. I want to login as different user. We only have username and password hash.